# How to create file named with "\?$*’MaRViN’*$?\" that include double quotes by shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a file named `"\?$*’MaRViN’*$?\"` . Name should have all characters that I write.

Comment: `touch $'"?$’MaRViN’$?"'`

Comment: actually should include reverse slash sorry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact answer is:

```
touch "\"\\?\$*'MaRViN'*\$?\\\""
```

Comment: Better to use single quotes. This way you will avoid all these backscapes.

Comment: I have to use cat -e so the command should show the file name as same as i asked so the answer is right but deficient.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the name into single quotes

```
touch '"\?$*’MaRViN’*$?\"'
```

Comment: The only special character when using single quotes is a single quote. Which marks the end of the quoted string. To type a single quote it's common to end single quotes, write an escaped single quote and start single quotes again, eg: `'Conan O'\''Brien'` or `'Conan O'"'"'Brien'`

Comment: when I write 'ls -lRa * MaR * | cat  -e' it doesn't return orijinal file name. How can I fix it.

Comment: @MuhammedErem, do you know what  `-e` flag means?

Comment: Yes displays non-printing chars but I think that's the point. Im confused.

Comment: @MuhammedErem Some versions of `echo` interpret `-e` as meaning they should interpret some escape sequences in the string; some other versions just print "-e" as part of their output. It's inconsistent, so I recommend against using it. Similarly, some versions of `ls` will print raw filenames, while others will try to add quotes and/or escapes to filenames with weird characters (but not in a way that's compatible with `echo -e`). In short, this is a really bad way to print the file's actual name.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Appreciate your advice and comment. I'll consider your advices when i use for my jobs. But this is the task to use  -e.